# Confirmation when a dropdown list control's value changes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I have the following code in my aspx (using C# for the code behind).

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConfirm" runat="server" </asp:DropDownList>
```

There are two values. Yes and No.

Initially, the value will be Yes. I want to show a confirmation popup box as soon as the user selects NO (before any submit or anything is clicked).

How can I do that?

Comment: This occurs on the client. Your server-side code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jQuery to display a message.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConfirm" runat="server" OnChange="ddlConfirmClick()">
</asp:DropDownList>
function ddlConfirmClick() {
   if ($('#<%= ddlConfirm.ClientID %>').val() == "NO") {
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?")){
         // do something.
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that in the javascript.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function() { HookUpEvent(); }

    function HookUpEvent()
    {
        var comboBox= document.getElementById ( "MyComboId" );
        comboBox.onchange = function () { OnComboSelected( this ); }
    }

    function OnComboSelected(selectedElement)
    {
        if(selectedElement.value == 'No')
        {
           alert('Your warning message!');
        } 
        return false;  
    }
</script>
```

Please not that the key here is the `return false;` - you need that to prevent the page from posting back.

You can conditionally continue with the postback by simply returning `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#<%= ddlConfirm.ClientID %>').change(function(){
        //on-change code goes in here.
        if (this.val() == "NO") {
        alert("message")
}
    });
```